# Android Vibrate with screen off

Tags: android, wakelock, android-vibration

Considering the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329533/allow-phone-to-vibrate-when-screen-turns-off) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960877/vibration-even-when-the-screen-has-timed-out) are not providing an actual solution to the same problem and are more than a year old...

I have a `Vibrator`. I know how to fully control the vibrator.

I have the following two issues:

- When it's vibrating and the screen is being locked, it will stop.
- When the screen is already locked, it will not vibrate at all.

Maybe it's due to the fact I use a custom rom(?)

I'm also holding a wakelock before starting to vibrate.

```
vibratorWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, VIBRATOR_WL_TAG);
vibratorWakeLock.acquire();
```

Even with this WakeLock i cannot get the phone to vibrate, or to maintain the vibration when Screen is turned off, so i think that it's somehow related to the state of the screen instead of the processor (which is enabled by my WakeLock).

- How can I get my vibrator to really vibrate independent from the screen lock-state?

---

**EDIT:**

I also do not want to use a full WakeLock, since it's deprecated.